# Extract pixel coordinates and paste on new image python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

[image]

This code is **returning pixels coordinates** which have **red color** now i want to extract and paste those pixels on new image. how do i paste pixel coordinates? Please ask if question is not clear.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
filename = "oOHc6.png"
img = cv2.imread(filename, 1)
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_lower=np.uint8([0, 200, 210])
hsv_upper=np.uint8([180, 250, 250])
mask= cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_lower, hsv_upper)

#display mask
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
res_gray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ys,xs = np.where(res_gray>0)
pts = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(xs,ys)]

empty = np.zeros_like(img)
mask_c = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
imaskc = mask_c>0

empty[imaskc] = img[imaskc]
#empty.save('C:/Python27/cclabel/images/NewImage'+'.png','png')
cv2.imwrite("new.png", empty)
```

Comment: Edit your code, post the part which is absolutely necessary to replicate your problem. Remove all the commented code, file I/O and other lines of code which is not required for this post.

Comment: What do you mean by "This code is returning pixels coordinates which have `red color` now i want to extract and paste those pixels on new image." I don't think this code is written for this... You want the red color regions coords, but you do harris corners detection? I think you should use `inRange` color selection in HSV space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do `cv2.inRange()` in HSV-space to get the mask for the red region:

[image]

Then use the mask-operation(such as cv2.bitwise_and()/np.where()/ slices) to "paste" to another image.

[image]

---

To get the coords, you can also use the np.where() like that.

```
# 使用 cv2.bitwise_and 掩模操作，然后使用 np.where 获取坐标
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
res_gray = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ys,xs = np.where(res_gray>0)
pts = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(xs,ys)]
```

---

To "copy-paste" into another same size image:

```
## 复制-粘贴到其他空白的地方
empty = np.zeros_like(img)
mask_c = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
imaskc = mask_c>0
empty[imaskc] = img[imaskc]
```

Comment: I edited the code after np.where when i print corrds array is empty can you check the code.

Comment: Actually, let me know, what do you really want to do? To get and save the coords? Or to pate into another image? Or anything?

Comment: I edited  in my answer(only for the same size and dtype).

Comment: @MunazzaAli Cann't you debug it by yourself? I'm busy now.

Comment: It worked like charm thank you i want to add a small detail what if i want to extract every component on separate image, i mean not only red but for every color.

Comment: 我现在很忙啊，大半夜的我还在调试我自己的代码。你就不可以独立自主思考么？